# Can't display the entities for the owner of the entity?

Tags: java, spring-security, jhipster

I'm trying to let the user of my jhipster application just access for the entity that he created this is my code :

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long> {

@Query("select blog from Blog blog where blog.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
List<Blog> findAllForCurrentUser();
}
```

My BlogResource :

```
@Timed
public List<Blog> getAll() {
 log.debug("REST request to get all Blogs for current user");
 return blogRepository.findAllForCurrentUser();
 }



<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
<version>${spring-security.version}</version>
<scope>test</scope>
```

In BlogResourceTest:

```
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext context;

@Inject
UserRepository userRepository;

 @Test

  @Transactional

  public void getAllBlogs() throws Exception {
restBlogMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();

 // Initialize the database
 blog.setUser(userRepository.findOneByLogin("user").get());
 blogRepository.saveAndFlush(blog);

 // Get all the blogs
restBlogMockMvc.perform(get("/api/blogs").with(user("user")))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(blog.getId().intValue())))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].name").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_NAME.toString())))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].handle").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_HANDLE.toString())));
```

}

But my problem is that when the user create some entity , there is no entity displayed for him , I don't know why ? Did I miss any thing? just to notice my blog entity has a many to one relationship  with the user entity .
Waiting for your help ...

Comment: is the data in the database correct? can you turn on sql debugging to show the actual sql sent to the db?

Comment: yes the data  is inserted in the database, but discover the problem and I couldn't solve it : in fact, I have an attribute user who is the owner of the entity ,this attribute should automatically get the user authenticated, but I can't do it